# Write text to a string if an if statement returns true and and different text if else

Tags: java, string, integer

OK, so here what I need. I have an if statement that if it returns true, then to add text to a string, and if it is else, then add different text to the same string. Heres my code:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.*; 
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

      public class theclock extends JFrame {
      theclock() {
         final JLabel timeField = new JLabel();
         timeField.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 20));

         Container content = this.getContentPane();
         content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         content.add(timeField); 

         setTitle("Norway");
         setSize(150,70);

         javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
             String a = ""; //empty string that I want to add text to
             String h = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+8); //I know its not the easiest way to add 8 hours, but im experimenting.
                int i = Integer.parseInt(h);
                    if (i>12)
                    {
                          i=i-12;
                          a = "A.M"; //what to add to the string if it is true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         i=i; //haven't applied myself to this part yet, so i know its probably wrong, but its just a place holder
                         a = "P.M"; //for when it is else, i should say pm.
                    }
             String m = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
             String s = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
             timeField.setText("" + i + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + a); //where the string is shown.
             }
         });
         t.start(); 
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame clock = new theclock();
         clock.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it not working? It looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Also have you considered using SimpleDateFormat? It's a Date Formatter that's, well, pretty simple to use.

Comment: well, see, the things is, my teacher for java at school told me to do it this way, to see how i can resolve "complicated things" so, i need to find a way to replace the empty string with am/pm

Comment: Nevermind! I just got it to work, turns out, i didnt have else in my code, so it disregarded if because it didnt have the ; since else was missing :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to append to the string you could use:

```
if (i>12)
{
    i=i-12;
    a = a + "A.M"; //appends 'A.M' to the string if the string already has a value
} 
else 
{
    i=i;
    a = a + "P.M"; //appends 'P.M' to the string if the string already has a value
}
```